# auto updating text value Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter. I'm trying to make a simple automatically updating time.

I tried with `RefreshIndicator` but it didn't work for me. What is the correct way to make it update per second? Is it possible to make it update with the `setState` in the `bottomNavigationBar` by making recursion function?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1TZ7.png)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

int Currentindex = 0 ;

late String time1;
var today = DateTime.now();

String time()
{
  today = DateTime.now();
   time1 = (today.hour.toString()+" : "+today.minute.toString()+" : "+today.second.toString());
  return time1;
}
  
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp( debugShowCheckedModeBanner : false ,
      home: Firstpage()
      ,);
  }
}

class Firstpage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Firstpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirstpageState createState() => _FirstpageState();
}

class _FirstpageState extends State<Firstpage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp( debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Currentindex == 0 ? Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)
              {
                return SecondPage();
              }
              )
              );
            });
          }, child: Text("Click me"))],

          ) : Currentindex == 1 ? Column(mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.center,children: [Text(time(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 80),)], ):
          SizedBox()
        ) ,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "Icecream",icon: Icon(Icons.icecream , color: Colors.white,)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "Time",icon: Icon(Icons.access_time , color: Colors.white,))],
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      onTap: (int index){setState(() {

        if(Currentindex == 1){today = DateTime.now();;}

        Currentindex = index;
      });},
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp( debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold( backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Cool"),backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context){return Firstpage();
                }
                )
                );
              }
              );
            }, child: Text("Go back"), style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.yellow , onPrimary: Colors.orange),)],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make it look like a clock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if it helps. Ideally this kind of widget (that updates all the time) should be in leafs and by themselves, to avoid rebuilding parts of your tree unnecessarily.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget();
  
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyWidget();
}
class _MyWidget extends State<MyWidget> {
  String lastTime = '';
  
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    timeUpdate.listen((time) => setState(() => lastTime = time ));
  }
  
  
  String get time => DateTime.now().toString();
  
  Stream<String> get timeUpdate async* {
    while(true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
     yield time;
    }
  }

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      time,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make a digital clock looking thing, try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class ClockWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  const ClockWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1)),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Text(
          DateFormat('HH:mm:ss')
                  .format(DateTime.now().toLocal())
                  .toString(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```